# Getting the right "this" scope in jQuery on

Tags: javascript, jquery

In replacing all the `.live()` functions in our project I used `.on` usually like this:

```
$("body").on("click","#someElement",function(e){...
```

Now we didn't always use `body`.

In the callback functions we used `$(this)` extensively. Which would have returned a jQuery object of `$("#someElement")` in the case of `.live`. Now because we are using `.on` it returns a jQuery object of `$("body")`.  How can I get the reference to `$("#someElement")` in the case of `.on` instead of a reference to `$("body")`?

We replaced all the `.live` with `.on` a library we wished to use that worked on jQuery 1.10 and `.live` and others were removed.

Comment: `this` should refer to `#someElement` inside the handler, even with delegated events. http://jsfiddle.net/3VtZY/ Can you provide an example where it doesn't?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski You are absolutely correct. In this horrible code I have taken over the person was assigning events in a giant for loop. I took the events out of the for loop and everything worked as you predicted.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into an issue where a child element is getting hit, and not what you have actually selected.  You can get around this by using `e.currentTarget`.

http://api.jquery.com/event.currenttarget/